# Permisson Denied Error with Kivy sample code

Tags: kivy, python-3.8, permission-denied, buildozer

I was testing buildozer with Kivy test code below:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

TestApp().run()
```

This code is sample code in Kivy website.

But I build apk with buildozer, it occurs this error:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I followed [Rock Koder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K7iRNO013D8)'s video, and in comment, Rock Koder said 'Try it as admin or root' but I don't understand this.

I'm using Windows 10 and I used WSL to run buildozer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSL does not work very well with kivy and buildozer, (believe me, I have tried many times), and also you don't get good functionality like deploy and run, since you can't share the USB between WSL, I'd recommend using an Ubuntu 20.04 VM and then installing the buildozer dependencies.

Comment: I hoped I can do this with WSL... I'll use Ubuntu VM. Thanks!